# Set value - instance variables

Tags: objective-c, instance-variables

I'm learning Objectice-c and I notice that I can set the values of instace variables in two ways

```
@interface Foo : NSObject
  @property int x;
  -(void)print;
@end

@implementation Foo

 -(void)print
 {
   [self setX:10] // first way
   x = 10; // second way 
 }
@end
```

I personally prefer the first method as it's look more clear. Is it ok to use the first method in my projects?

Comment: Use the setter outside of `init` and `dealloc`.  Use the ivar directly in those two methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access your variable in two ways:

Using the setter or getters with self. :

```
self.x = 10;
[self setX:10]
```

Both are equivalent, but Apple recommends you to use the setter with self.

Or accessing the ivar directly. The ivar name depends on how you shynthesize it. If you use the default synthesize (or you don't synthesize it yourself), is like this:

```
_x = 10;
```

In you example, the second way is accessing the ivar directly, and the first way is using the setter (same as self.x = 10),

The first way is recommended (using self or using the setter) because it takes care of memory issues, releases previous values, protect from threads if you want, etc. And it's more comfortable to use self. than calling the setter.

Only use the ivar when you are in the **init** method, for the rest, use the setter.